How do I interpolate wix variables into a text file during installation?
When packaging a native messaging browser extension using Wix, part of the install process requires that a json file containing something similar to the following be installed alongside the application:
{
  "allowed_extensions": [ "ext@exammple.com" ],
  "description": "Native Extension",
  "name": "com.example.Native.Extension",
  "path": "c:\path\to\application.exe",
  "type": "stdio"
}

How do I tell Wix to filter the text file above to insert the destination path to replace "c:\path\to\application.exe" into the text above at install time with the full path to the application being installed by Wix?
Most specifically, I assume I want to have Wix variables interpolated in the text.
If the answer is to use a Wix extension, what extension specifically? Can this be done through localisation?

This is possible using the FormatFile element from the Util extension. It's pretty easy to use.
<Binary Id="FormatThis" Source="path\to\template.txt" />

<Component>
  <File Source="path\to\textthatgetsoverwritten.txt">
     <util:FormatFile BinaryRef="FormatThis" />


Unless something has changed, I don't believe this is possible "out of the box".
If your file were an XML file, you could add a reference to wixUtilExtension.dll and then use the <util:XmlFile> tag. (There's a tutorial here.)
This is most commonly used to modify config files during installation. Depending on your use case, maybe you could include an XML file with your installation and reference that instead.
If that isn't suitable, you will need to use a WiX custom action. There's an illustration of something similar in this Q&A. Your best bet is probably to use the Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) framework - see e.g. here for an introduction. You should need very little custom code for this.
Alternatively, instead of writing your own custom action, you could try an off-the-shelf WiX extension. For the use case you describe, you could try something like TextReplace, which should allow you to replace some placeholder string in your JSON file with the application's target folder (via a WiX variable) during installation.
(I have found DTF to be very good but you do need to dig a bit to find what you need. If you do need a custom action, and require additional help, I can post some further links or sample code.)
